# Hadoop, gcloud utilities, bdutils within Cygwin. No connection, commands not recognized

Tags: python, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, gcloud

Not sure where the Hadoop forum is...this seems closest bet.

I am trying to set up the cluster to run the Hortonworks platform, meaning I need bdutil working.

However, while I can run the install.py script inside the bootstrapping folder, I can not get any of the gcloud or bdutil functions to work.  I initially thought there was incompatibility between the 64 bit python install and the 32 bit GC SDK...so, installed a 32 bit Python 2.7 and forced Cygwin to use this path by temporarily deleting the environmental variable with the path to the 64 bit install.

Below is a log of my errors, as well as info regarding contents of the dirs.  Assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I've been fighting with this for three days now.

```
--KNOWS WHICH PYTHON TO USE
$ which python/cygdrive/c/Users/MJ/Anaconda/python

--INSIDE FOLDER WITH PYTHON SCRIPTS
MJ@Speed_rAcer ~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping
$ ls
__init__.py        bq.py      install.py         setup.py
bootstrapping.py   gcutil.py  prerun.py          setup.pyc
bootstrapping.pyc  gsutil.py  print_env_info.py

--RUNS PYTHON SCRIPT (install.py).  DIDN'T LET ME PICK Y OR N BUT SAYS IT'S CONFIGURED
MJ@Speed_rAcer ~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping
$ python install.py

Do you want to help improve the Google Cloud SDK (Y/n)?

All components are up to date.

Update %PATH% to include Cloud SDK binaries? (Y/n)?

The Google Cloud SDK is currently in developer preview. To help improve the
quality of this product, we collect anonymized data on how the SDK is used.
You may choose to opt out of this collection now (by choosing 'N' at the below
prompt), or at any time in the future by running the following command:
    gcloud config set --scope=user disable_usage_reporting true


This will install all the core command line tools necessary for working with
the Google Cloud Platform.

The following directory has been added to your PATH.
  C:\Users\MJ\home\google-cloud-sdk\bin

Create a new command shell for the changes to take effect.


For more information on how to get started, please visit:
  https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/gettingstarted


--NEW SHELL.  SHOWING COMMANDS I SHOULD BE ABLE TO RUN (first is gcloud.cmd)
MJ@Speed_rAcer ~/google-cloud-sdk/bin
$ ls
bootstrapping  gcloud - Copy.cmd  gcutil.cmd                 gsutil.cmd
bq.cmd         gcloud.cmd         git-credential-gcloud.cmd  sdk

--TRY ONE TO EXECUTE COMMAND
$ ./gcloud auth login
-bash: ./gcloud: No such file or directory

--TRY TWO TO EXECUTE COMMAND
MJ@Speed_rAcer ~/google-cloud-sdk/bin
$ gcloud auth login
-bash: gcloud: command not found
```

Answer (score 4):

The Cloud SDK for Windows instructions are for Windows, where "command shell" means cmd.exe. `gcloud auth login` at the bash prompt instructs bash to find an executable file `gcloud` on PATH. You installed gcloud for Windows, so `gcloud.cmd` was installed. bash does not do suffix based search for commands, so it doesn't find `gcloud.cmd` when searching for `gcloud`.

You can do one of the following to get bash to recognize the `gcloud` command:

1. Run this to install the CygWin shell scripts:
   `gcloud.cmd components update`
2. Run:`alias gcloud='cmd /c gcloud.cmd'`
3. In the directory containing gcloud.cmd run:
   `echo cmd /c gcloud.cmd \"\$@\" > gcloud
   chmod +x gcloud`
4. Run `cmd` to get a Windows command prompt. You won't be in bash anymore.

Comment: I like the trick of a shell script that calls cmd! This doesn't automatically pass arguments, though - I added a `$@` for that, hope you don't mind the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That will work for uncomplicated args (no embedded " or ').